# How to rotate label in OpenLayers 2.13?

Tags: openlayers-2

I need custom rotation in feature text labels. Although this functionality is available in OL3, but at this moment I am unable to migrate to OL3 from Ol2.

I have tried changing SVG code at some levels, but nothing worked.

Comment: Can you show something you have tried? Text is something of a pain in OL2 generally -- I spent many hours staring at the VML and SVG renderers to try and do simple things like add a border and background colour.

Comment: I have used this - http://benjamin.preisig.at/rotating-labels-in-openlayers/

Comment: Which works, whereas what you have done, doesn't. So, without seeing your code, it is going to be hard for us to debug.

Comment: Have you tried above stated link?

Comment: The link above is not working anymore. I've created a gist with the same content and a patch https://gist.github.com/prebm/52da803602cb251e779fc2f416aa69e5